# Need Help on this complex report

Tags: visual-studio, reporting

I have to create a report on Microsoft Reports in Visual Studio 2008. I have an Author Table, a books Table and a shops table that has these books.

Now, I need to get all authors from authors table based on its author_ID, I need to display all the books of that author and then all shops of that are selling the books of that author.

So each page will be like this:

```
    -Author Name

     |---Books of this author [I am using List]

       |----Book 1

       |----Book 2

       |----Book 3

       |----Book 4

     |----Shops Selling these books [Again List in a Sub Report, Author_ID as Parameter]

       |----Shop1

       |----Shop2

       |----Shop3

       |----Shop4
-------------------------------------
```

Then Repeat the same layout in the next page for the next author. Its getting complex as I am putting this whole layout in a list and then using list for Books of that author and then a subreport with list to display Shops. Is there any simple way to do it? Any Idea would be a great help.

Comment: Never mind I solved it using Sub reports.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never mind I solved it using Sub reports.